# When and where did the LLVM IR Instruction set it's parent BasicBlock?

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir

When I insert an Instruction into a BasicBlock with the method

```
BasicBlock::getInstList().push_front(*Instruction);
```

But when did it set the Instruction's parent to current BasicBlock?

The code is as follow and worked well. I just want to know when and where set the parent of the cloned Instruction.

Thanks.

```
Instruction *ori_inst = cur_inst->clone();  
//until now, the ori_inst does not have it's parent
CUR_BB->getInstList().push_front(ori_inst); 
//now, the ori_inst has CUR_BB as it's parent, why?
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is getting set in

```
void SymbolTableListTraits<ValueSubClass,ItemParentClass>
      ::addNodeToList(ValueSubClass *V) {
```

in `lib/IR/SymbolTableListTraitsImpl.h`

`addNodeToList` is invoked by `ilist`'s `insert` method, which is called by `push_front`. Thus, whenever you add an instruction to an instruction list in a basic block, its parent is automatically set to the basic block itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot. But how did the iplist call this addNodeToList() ?    In "ilist.h" it looks like "void addNodeToList(NodeTy *) {}", would you please tell me how did it call the one in lib/IR/SymbolTableListTraitsImpl.h ? Thanks

Comment: @UDNightWish: through the traits mechanism. If you're having trouble following it through the code, I suggest just putting a breakpoint in the leaf method in gdb and then looking at the stack trace.

Comment: May be I have trouble in understanding C++ templete code. Thank you for your guide !